# Cloud solutions eg Snowflake for server data filling up fast

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cloud

Firstly I'm new to development and  currently I have a problem with server data filling up rapidly. I'm looking at solutions such as watcher programs to help me detect when the server data is reaching the limit but I wanted to know if cloud solutions could help in this regard. Additionally I also wanted to know if companies such as Snowflake can help to handle fast growing data and in what way can a developer use it or will it be too costly to use this approach from an enterprise point of view.

I have tried to look up the documentations of Snowflake but I am unable to reach any conclusions as to whether it can help me. I could just see articles about storage and that they store data by compressing it but I wanted more clarity on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake stores the data using Cloud Storege Services (AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure), so you can't fill the server data in normal conditions (never heard that S3 is full on any region).

Check the pricing page to see if it will be costly for you (or not):

https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/